# John 4 Jesus and the Samaritan Woman at the Well (John 4:1-26)

Tags: john

Is there a translation of this Chapter in John that says Jesus told the woman not to tell anyone he is the Messiah?

I need clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge, but I have no idea what it would take to prove to someone the absence of a translation. You can go to [biblehub](http://biblehub.com/john/4-1.htm) and read 20+ translations at the same time and confirm for yourself. There are, however, many other places throughout the Gospels where Jesus instructs someone not to tell people that He is the Messiah.

Comment: Yes, I think the OP might be conflating this passage with Mark 1:41-42 for example.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean, "Are there any manuscripts ...".

According to the Nestle-Aland apparatus, almost every verse in this passage has some variant.  But these are all relatively minor; there doesn't appear to be any variant where what you suggest occurs.

Since there are no manuscripts that have Jesus forbidding the woman to tell anyone, we should be able to safely assume that there are also no translations that show this.